# Every time I restart the computer the link for Atom stops working

Tags: terminal, unix

I use the Atom editor and I like to open it from the command line. For that purpose I execute the following line:

```
ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom
```

The problem is that if I restart the computer, the link stops working, so I have to delete the file

```
rm /usr/local/bin/atom
```

and execute the first line to create the link again. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: What does `less /usr/local/bin/atom` show after a reboot? And `ls -l /usr/local/bin/atom /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it myself and it worked perfectly, even after a reboot. Do you have multiple disks/partitions in you set up?

Anyway, to settle things once and for all, I suggest you to follow the steps pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23666354). Below is a copy&paste.

With the Atom editor open, in the menu bar:

Click Atom >> Install Shell Commands

[image]

You should expect to see:

[image]

You do not need to restart the terminal.

If this solution didn't work, my last suggestion is to create an alias in your `~/.bash_profile`. To do this, simply open `~/.bash_profile` with a text editor and add somewhere the line:

`alias atom='open -a Atom'`

This should do the trick.

**EDIT**

I noticed that after a reboot, you must start Atom at least once before the `atom` command works - otherwise it won't be recognized as a command. I didn't notice it before because, while testing if the `ln -s ...` solution worked, I already opened Atom once. I honestly don't have a clue why this happens, but the last suggestion about adding an alias definitely solves this issue.

Comment: sorry, it did not really worked. When I restart the computer it does not work anymore and I have the same behaviour as before

Comment: Did you try the "alias" solution?

Comment: sorry I didn't realize the alias solution, it worked. However, I will try to understand why the ```ln -s``` is not working. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you!! This answer is the best for this issue. I Google searched for days, and before this, all I found was either variations of that Stack Overflow answer or sassy devs arguing with each other.  So thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure Atom app is actually executing from the Applications folder and then install the Shell Commands utility.
I was executing Atom from my Downloads folder and every time I rebooted the atom commands weren't recognized.